# How to create a Spacer style Widget that prints dots?

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I'm looking at the [Material.io Basil design study](https://material.io/design/material-studies/basil.html), and I'm trying to figure out how to make a Flutter Widget acts like a `Spacer`, but with content.

[image: Basil's ingredients listing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `CustomPainter` with `TextPainter` to fill the available width with a `.`

[image]

Example:

```
class PointPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final point = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: ".", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    point.layout(maxWidth: size.width);

    for (double i = 0; i < size.width; i += point.width) {
      point.paint(canvas, Offset(i, .0));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You'd normally pass the text theme as parameter, but for example purposes let's skip it.

It can then be used within a `Row` using an `Expanded`:

```
Expanded(
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: PointPainter(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: How to make it center vertically?